# Checkbox angular material checked by default

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, angular-material2

I am trying to use an Angular Material checkbox, and set it by default as checked, but it is displayed as non-checked, what is wrong?

```
<mat-checkbox class = "example-margin" [(ngModel)] = obj.impresora> 
     <label>Printer</label> 
</mat-checkbox>
```

obj.impresora property is boolean

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can either set with ngModel either with [checked] attribute. 
ngModel binded property should be set to 'true':

1.

```
  <mat-checkbox class = "example-margin" [(ngModel)] = "myModel"> 
    <label>Printer </label> 
  </mat-checkbox>
```

2.

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]= "myModel" class = "example-margin" > 
    <label>Printer </label> 
</mat-checkbox>
```

3.

```
<mat-checkbox [ngModel]="myModel" class="example-margin">
    <label>Printer </label> 
</mat-checkbox>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-list-nav-menu-item-ctrxbd)

Comment: I'm new to Angular. Could you/somebody point me in a direction as to the pros/cons of each of these styles? Just trying to figure out what's happening / why I'd choose one way over another.

Comment: Based on the Angular documentation, it looks like the second method might be the better way to start off using: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions .

Comment: @user3773048, it depends what you are trying to achive. The first one would do two-way binding, i.e. the model will be updated from template. The two other are one-way and you can update the model programatically

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you very much for this explanation. I'll have to look more into that. Getting 2-way binding, as you put it, seems like a nice thing to be able to get for free. Hm, I see, I could imagine what the difference between methods 2 and 3 would entail. Interesting / will have to look into this further.

Answer (score 12):

this works for me in Angular 7

```
// in component.ts
checked: boolean = true;

changeValue(value) {
    this.checked = !value;
}

// in component.html
<mat-checkbox value="checked" (click)="changeValue(checked)" color="primary">
   some Label
</mat-checkbox>
```

I hope help someone ... greetings.
let me know if someone have some easiest

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you can achieve this based on the approach you take. For reactive approach, you can pass the default value to the constructor of the FormControl(import from @angular/forms)

```
this.randomForm = new FormGroup({
      'amateur': new FormControl(false),
});
```

Instead of true or false value, yes you can send variable name as well like `FormControl(this.booleanVariable)`

In template driven approach you can use 1 way binding `[ngModel]="this.booleanVariable"` 
or 2 way binding `[(ngModel)]="this.booleanVariable"` like this

```
<mat-checkbox
     name="controlName"
     [(ngModel)]="booleanVariable">
     {{col.title}}
</mat-checkbox>
```

You can also use the checked directive provided by angular material and bind in similar manner

Answer (score 3):

The chosen answer does work however I wanted to make a comment that having 'ngModel' on the html tag causes the checkbox checked to not be set to true.

This occurs when you are trying to do bind using the checked property. i.e.

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]='var' ngModel name='some_name'></mat-checkbox>
```

And then inside your app.component.ts file

```
var = true;
```

will not work.

TLDR: Remove ngModel if you are setting the checked through the [checked] property

```
    <mat-checkbox [checked]='var' name='some_name'></mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Setting the checkbox checked from the template:

`<mat-checkbox checked="true"> I accept </mat-checkbox>`

---

**Option 2:** Setting the value dynamically.

In the **component.html** file

`<mat-checkbox [checked]="isChecked"> I accept </mat-checkbox>`

inside the **component.ts file**

```
 isChecked:boolean;
 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isChecked = true;  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the **`checked`** property to be true inside the component.ts

```
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {
 checked = true;
}
```

Comment: I wanna set de property of type bool "impresora" like this: <mat-checkbox class = "example-margin" [(ngModel)] = "obj.impresora"> <label>Printer </ label> 
</ mat-checkbox>

Comment: then impersora should be true

Comment: Yes but doesn´t work, the checkbox remains unchecked

Comment: it should , can you create a plunker

Comment: It works when the property is string type obj.impresora = "true" but my objt.impresora is boolean, would you recommend that I create a pipe to evaluate the value and return it as a string type?

Comment: you could just cast it

Comment: Where could I cast it, in the ts component?

Comment: yes inside the component, usualy it should work with boolean, not sure why its not in your case

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this code on you component:

```
export class Component {
  checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Reactive form you can set it to default like this:

In the form model, set the value to false. So if it's checked its value will be true else false

```
let form = this.formBuilder.group({
    is_known: [false]
})
```

//In HTML

```
 <mat-checkbox matInput formControlName="is_known">Known</mat-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this in HTML:

```
    <div class="modal-body " [formGroup]="Form">
        <div class="">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="a" [disabled]="true"> Display 1</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="b"  [disabled]="true">  Display 2 </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="c"  [disabled]="true">  Display 3 </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="d"  [disabled]="true">  Display 4</mat-checkbox>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="e"  [disabled]="true"> Display 5 </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Changes in Ts file

```
this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
a: false,
b: false,
c: false,
d: false,
e: false,
});
```

Conditionvalidation in Ur Business logic

```
if(true){
this.Form.patch(a: true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For check it with ngModel, make a merge between "ngModel" and "value", Example:

```
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myVariable"  value="1" >Subscribe</mat-checkbox>
```

Where, myVariable = 1

Greeting

Answer (score 0):

```
// in component.ts
checked: boolean = true;
indeterminate:boolean = false;
disabled:boolean = false;
label:string;

onCheck() {
    this.label = this.checked?'ON':'OFF';
}

// in component.html`enter code here`
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [color]="primary" [(ngModel)]="checked" [(indeterminate)]="indeterminate" [labelPosition]="after" [disabled]="disabled" (change)="onCheck()">
                    {{label}}
                  </mat-checkbox>
```

The above code should work fine. 
Mat checkbox allows you to make it checked/unchecked, disabled, set indeterminate state, do some operation onChange of the state etc. 
Refer [API](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

`<mat-checkbox [attr.checked] = "myCondition ? 'checked' : null">`

if the checked attribute is set to null, it gets removed from the html tag

or you can use Vega's anwser which should work too (mine is a completion that can be usefull if you don't want to link it with ngModel)