# Material Checkbox checked property not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

`mat-checkbox` isn't default checked when `checked` property is set to true:

```
<mat-checkbox value="true" formControlName="updates" checked="true">Get Updates</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Do you have to dynamically mark the check box as checked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkbox angular material checked by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162651/checkbox-angular-material-checked-by-default)

Answer (score 5):

NOT use checked. if you have used Reactive Forms then just set a value to the field

```
//When you create the form
this.form=new FormGroup({
   updates:new FormControl(true)
}
//Or in a function
this.form.get('updates').setValue(true)

<!--no value, no checked, just formControlName-->
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <mat-checkbox formControlName="updates" >Get Updates</mat-checkbox>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set with ngModel with [checked] attribute. ngModel binded property should be set to 'true':

component.html:

```
<mat-checkbox class = "example" [(ngModel)] = "myModel"> 
    <label>Hello example true </label> 
</mat-checkbox>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-component-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  myModel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use two way binding.

```
<mat-checkbox value="true" formControlName="updates" [checked]="true">Get Updates</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: here is the stackblitz that I created and checked.https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-h3m2gx?file=app/checkbox-overview-example.html

Comment: @HameedSyed, if you use ReactiveForm NOT use [checked]. NOTE: In your stackblitz change [checked]=true by [checked]="isChecked" (but only because you're not using ReactiveForm or [(ngModel)] in your stackblitz)

Answer (score 1):

As far as Reactive forms are concerned, I haven't found a way to dynamically check a checkbox and update the form control's value.

Using `[checked]` just checks the HTML checkbox element, but doesn't affect the control.

If you have to handle the checkbox dynamically depending on a variable's value, then you can use this approach.

Have setters and getters for the variable which decides the checked state, update the form control in the setter.

Something like:

```
private _checkBoxChecked = false

set checkBoxChecked(val) {
  this._checkBoxChecked = val
  this.form.get('con').setValue(this.checkBoxChecked); // update your checbox control here
}

get checkBoxChecked() {
  return this._checkBoxChecked
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
    con: [this.checkBoxChecked]
  })
}
```

See an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hba5pt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In the added example, it is normal input checkbox not a mat-input checkbox, but ideally this approach should work for that too.

Comment: chaning `[checked]` to `[ngModel]` fixed the issue... I don't know why

Comment: @dcp3450 don't mix template driven style with reactive form style, when you use reactive forms, don't use anything related to ngModel. It will give you bugs which will be very difficult to resolve.

Comment: @xyz, not use an auxiliar variable, just use `this.form.get('con').value`

Comment: @Eliseo I don't follow, where should I use `this.form.get('con').value`?

Comment: in your checkBoxChecked function you can return simply this.form.get('con').value -if you want you can use `return this.form?this.form.get('con').value:false` to avoid error if this.form are not defined

Comment: @Eliseo yeah, But I am also using the `checkBoxChecked`  property during form initialization, if you would look at the stackblitz. I will better update the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago, there are several options:

1. You can use the property [(ngModel)] = varboolean
2. You can set the attribute [checked] = varboolean
3. You can default the value via formcontrol in its creation:

varboolean is a declared variable of type boolean marked by default with value "true":

public varboolean: boolean = true;

```
<mat-checkbox value="true" formControlName="updates" [(ngModel)] = varboolean >Get Updates</mat-checkbox>

<mat-checkbox value="true" formControlName="updates" [checked] = varboolean >Get Updates</mat-checkbox>


createForm() 
{
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({           
      updates: new FormControl(true, [Validators.nullValidator]), 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 10+, you can bind a [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#initializing-form-controls) to an HTML input element of type checkbox to a model in your controller.

You don't need to bind to `[checked]` or `[(ngModel)]` in your HTML code if you use pure a ReactiveForm implementation. Binding the `[formControlName]` directive to a `FormGroup` control will provide this functionality out of the box. Make sure your controls are defined in a `<form>` element which is bound to a `FormGroup`. Your HTML should resemble this:

```
<form [formGroup]='myForm'>
  <input type='checkbox' [formControlName]='"enabled'" />
</form>
```

In your controller:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-form',
  templateUrl: './my-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-form.component.scss']
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public createForm: FormGroup;
  public myModel = {
    checked: false
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      // value: false will uncheck the checkbox by default,
      // value: true will check the checkbox by default
      // IMPORTANT: The disabled property is REQUIRED for binding to work
      'enabled': new FormControl({
        value: this.myModel.checked, 
        disabled: false // required for model binding to work!
      })

      // this simpler form works, too:
      // 'enabled': new FormControl(this.myModel.checked)
    });
  }
}
```

If you use this approach, it's very important to note in the [Initializing Form Controls section](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#initializing-form-controls) of the FormControl documentation that:

> The following example initializes the control with a form state object. The value and disabled keys are required in this case.

```
// example given in documentation:
const control = new FormControl({ value: 'n/a', disabled: true });
```

If you attempt to initialize the FormControl as `new FormControl({value: false})` without specifying the `disabled` property, the checkbox value will not be bound and it will render as checked by default.

If you

You can programmatically update the value of this checkbox by using the [patchValue()](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#patchvalue) method:

```
// ...in your controller...
// no need to specify disabled property here
this.myForm.patchValue({'enabled': false});
```

Also note that using [formControlName] and [(ngModel)] together was [deprecated in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918503/angular-6-warning-for-using-formcontrolname-and-ngmodel), so that approach isn't ideal since using those two directives together may get removed in the future.